# Lost access to edit files on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

For some reason, after adding one line:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {:path =>"newApp/assets"}
```

to my config/application.rb file, now I can't edit any file on this Cloud9 folder. When I tried to delete it, Cloud9 says:

> Failed to delete folder 'newApp'. Command failed: rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/422.html’: Permission denied rm:
>   cannot remove ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/system’:
>   Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/robots.txt’: Permission denied
>   rm: cannot remove ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/images’:
>   Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/baec6461b0d69dde1b861aefbe375d8a20150413-9080-i8p3xh.jpeg’:
>   Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/500.html’: Permission denied rm:
>   cannot remove ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/favicon.ico’:
>   Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/404.html’: Permission denied rm:
>   cannot remove ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/public/app’: Permission
>   denied rm: cannot remove ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/app/views’:
>   Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/app/mailers’: Permission denied rm:
>   cannot remove ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/app/assets’: Permission
>   denied rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/app/baec6461b0d69dde1b861aefbe375d8a20150413-9135-kfwefx.jpeg’:
>   Permission denied rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/app/controllers’: Permission denied rm:
>   cannot remove ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/app/helpers’: Permission
>   denied rm: cannot remove ‘/home/ubuntu/workspace/newApp/app/models’:
>   Permission denied .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the execute permissions are removed from the app directories. I do not know how that could be related to your config change. Fix it by executing 
`sudo chmod -R 755 ~/workspace/myApp` in the terminal.

Comment: This did give me some folders access back, but I lost a lot of other folders such as bin, config, db...